# Is there a simple way to set all the properties of an object to match another object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an class with properties, then I have a custom control with the same properties (or a subset rather) as the first object.

Currently, For each property, I essentially just set it manually. I'm just curious if there was an easier way. Would reflection help with this at all?

Comment: There are libraries that can do it for you, but they require configuration if the names are different.  Look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)

Comment: Property names are the same? This can easily be done with reflection, without the overhead.

Comment: @Aaron Yes. Though the control is a subset, it doesn't have all of the properties. It also has one additional one, but it doesn't have to have that additional one. Essentially I just want it to map the ones that it does have in common.

Comment: working on it now - subset doesn't matter. you just start with the subset, look at the full set, and have a default value for when it doesn't find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use Reflection

```
void Copy(object from, object to)
{
    Type fromType = from.GetType();
    Type toType = to.GetType();
    foreach(var prop in fromType.GetProperties()
                                .Where(p=>toType.GetProperty(p.Name)!=null))
    {
        toType.GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(to, prop.GetValue(from, null));
    }

}
```

Comment: Beat me to it :(